In terminal how do I rename files to sequential numbers whilst keeping the original order?
I want to rename an image sequence with even numbers. The image sequence is already named in order 1.tif, 2.tif, 3.tif, 4.tif, etc but I want them to be named 2.tif, 4.tif, 6.tif, 8.tif etc. (I need them to stay in that order because they are animation frames)
I tried:
num=0; for i in *; do mv "$i" "$(printf '%04d' $num).${i#*.}"; ((num+=2)); done

but it loses the original order.

From comments:

To make a long story short, I ended up with an fps that
is too low. I need to fill in the missing frames. I want to keep it in
multiples of 2 so that I can render the odd numbered frames to add to
the image sequence and make it complete. Otherwise I'll have to
re-render the whole sequence. Hope that makes sense


You could a slightly different naming convention for renamed files.

To make a long story short, I ended up with an fps that is too low. I need to fill in the missing frames. I want to keep it in multiples of 2 so that I can render the odd numbered frames to add to the image sequence and make it complete. Otherwise I'll have to re-render the whole sequence. Hope that makes sense

Often easier to do  this type of one off task in a spreadsheet. A spreadsheet lets you try different formulae or approaches and see the resulting simple commands without messing up the actual files.  One approach: List the files, put them in a column in the spreadsheet, reverse the order, use a formulae to produce mv command strings that rename the current file to 2 times the current number. Copy and run those in terminal, lines like mv 755.tif 1510.tif etc with the numbers going down.

I don't understand how you lose the original order. Could you change your mv  to mv -v and post the result of your commands, please?

Here's a suggestion:
for File in *; do mv -v "$File" "$( printf '%04d' $(( ${File%.*} * 2)) ).${File##*.}"; done

The statement printf '%04d' $(( ${File%.*} * 2)) strips the dot.extension part off the file name (thus leaving only the numerical prefix, supposedly), multiplies by two and formats the result as a four-digit integer, as per your requirements.
Output from a test run:
for File in *; do mv -v "$File" "$( printf '%04d' $(( ${File%.*} * 2)) ).${File##*.}"; done
renamed '10.tif' -> '0020.tif'
renamed '11.tif' -> '0022.tif'
renamed '12.tif' -> '0024.tif'
renamed '1.tif' -> '0002.tif'
renamed '2.tif' -> '0004.tif'
renamed '3.tif' -> '0006.tif'
renamed '4.tif' -> '0008.tif'
renamed '5.tif' -> '0010.tif'
renamed '6.tif' -> '0012.tif'
renamed '7.tif' -> '0014.tif'
renamed '8.tif' -> '0016.tif'
renamed '9.tif' -> '0018.tif'

Hope that helps!
